# What is the ARM MMU Memory Attribute 'P' field?

Tags: arm, armv7, mmu

I'm working on the L1 Descriptor MMU Table entries for an ARMv7A device and cannot find information about the '**P**' field from either the Cortex A-Series Programmer's Guide, or the Architecture reference manual for ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R. I have found information about all the other fields, including the `TEX` field, but am stuck on `P`.

Is this info in either of these two books (which section/chapter?) or in another manual.

According to Figure 9-5, page 9-8, of ARM DENN0013D (ARM Cortex-A Series Programmer's Guide), the entries to a Level 1 MMU page table has this format:

```
SectionBaseAddress : SBZ : 0 : nG : S : APX : TEX : AP : P : Domain : XN : C : B : 1 : 0
```

for a 1MB section entry.
But what does the 'P' bit (in-between the AP Access Permissions and deprecated Domain fields) mean? I can't find any information about "P".

Cheers.

Comment: Alright, I misread it. In manual that's `IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED`. That means manual for particular chip could have it. But in common sense, you likely should not need to use it.

Comment: You did not put the bit numbers.  TEX and AP are fields of 3 and 2 bits at positions 12-15 and 10-11.  A 'P' bit in positions 9 is a protection bit at L1 page table.  See: [pgtable-2level-hwdef.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/pgtable-2level-hwdef.h?h=v5.19-rc7#n24) for instance.  There are ARMv4/5 MMU as supported by later revisions [ARM on V4/5](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/cb/Appendixes/ARMv4-and-ARMv5-Differences/System-level-memory-model/Virtual-memory-support?lang=en#aGCaceafjg)